# How i can perform dynamic scrolling in VF page

Tags: visualforce

How i can perform dynamic scrolling in VF page. My vf page code is:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!getdata}" var="data" >
  <div>
            My code is here
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

i want to use dynamic scrolling in vf. If i scroll it down it should display new data..

My controller method is:

```
public List<List<List<Email__c>>> getdata()  
 {
       some code
 }
```

Comment: So you want to load data depending on the position of the div? If so i would recommend JavaScript Remoting http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

Comment: Actually my getdata() method will give me data i don't want to display all data while loading my page i want to load data when use will scroll vf page i.e like facebook.

Comment: Then calculate the position of the last visible row in the div and load data depending on that position. Use SOQL with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. E.g. if last visible row is 20 and you want load next 10 entries do `Select Name From Account ORDER BY Name LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20`

Comment: As you can see my getdata() method is returning List<List<List<Email__c>>> object to get this object i am using three different querry.

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry, I can't comment yet so putting this as an answer..)

Here's an example implementation of 'Infinite scrolling':
http://mavens.force.com/conversation/infinite-scrolling-lists-in-visualforce

Comment: This is more like an answer than a comment, so I don't think an apology is in order.